# d3, transitioning a scatterplot into a bar graph

Tags: d3.js

Looking at the d3 showreel (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1256572), the transitions are very smooth and beautiful. I'm trying to emulate this style to transition between a scatterplot and a bar graph.

I can do something like this:

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .delay(delay)
  .remove();

plot_bar_graph();
```

which removes the scatterplot and then plots the bar graph, but I would really like some sort of animation where the circles "turn into" rectangle elements, but am not sure how to do this.

My current idea is just to draw the circles in the scatterplot as rectangles, but give them an rx and ry attribute so they look like circles, then change them to rectangles.

Something like this:

```
d3.select(".bar")
   .transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .delay(delay)
   .attr("rx",0)
   .attr("ry",0);
```

but this seems rather unwieldy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the only way you can do it, short of writing your own tween and drawing with path elements (which is much harder). It's harder to set up, because rectangles draw from the top-left and not the center like circles, but it will work.

Tweens are hard but not impossible:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#attrTween

If you're interested in getting into tweening, you can see an extreme example here with Superformula (which includes rectangle-like and circle-like forms):

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1020902

Comment: Wow. Any suggestions for where to start with the tween? Or do you think that would be much more complicated than necessary?

Comment: Added some links. Yes, it's more complicated, but it also gives you more control. Since you're dealing with rect and circle, using rx/ry is much more convenient.

Comment: @user2631296 You can search here on SO for some other examples of custom path tweening.  However, I suspect the rx/ry transition is probably easier.  Just remember to add in an extra adjustment for your "circle" state, as Elijah pointed out, to account for the fact that rectangles are positioned from top-left, while scatterplot points should be centered on the data value.  So, you would be transitioning x and y slightly as well as rx, height, and width.  You *don't* need to transition ry separately: by default it is equal to rx.